# How to understand 'he trailed a sweater from one hand'?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

The sentence comes from *Lord Of The Flies*.

> Though he had taken off his school sweater and trailed it now from one hand, his grey shirt stuck to him and his hair was plastered to his forehead.

I want to know the meaning of 'trail a sweater from sb's hand'.

Comment: Ok.The sentense before is'Though he had taken off his school sweater and trailed it now from one hand, his grey shirt stuck to him and his hairwas plastered to his forehead'.Could the sentence replace the word 'plastered' with 'stuck'?

Comment: Please, edit your question and include the text of your comment for clarifications. Comments may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

"Trail" is a verb and has the common meaning "to drag or let drag along the ground or other surface; draw or drag along behind." (dictionary.com)

A (grey) sweater is a typical item of school uniform.

"from one hand" just means the sweater was held by one hand, and from that hand it went behind him.

> Tin cans trailed from the car bumper as the newly married couple left for their honeymoon.

The use of "plastered" is idiomatic, but it does mean roughly the same as "stuck". It implies that the boy is sweating heavily.